# Tail light fuse blown only when raining

Tags: fuse, tail-lights

I'm going to disassemble the left and right tail light assemblies to see if any signs of water. Does water have to get into contact with the tail light bulb connector to cause a short? I'm wondering because brake and hazard lights are in the same light assembly, but they still work.

Comment: The water doesn't necessarily have to be in the tail light assembly at all. Anywhere in the electrical system, all the way from the lights plug to the tail light, could have an electrical short, if the wire sheathing is worn off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably on the right track, and that's where I would start, keep in mind that any place where water could bridge the wires can be the cause of the short. Other than the assembly this could be:

- Connectors: modular connectors could be shorted by water. The back of the tail light assembly uses such a connector, but so does the other end of the wire, and possibly somewhere in between.
- Bare wires: if a wire's protective sheeting has been off the bare wires could be shorted
- The fuse board: If the fuse board got wet it could potentially short the tail light circuit. This is extremely unlikely though as if you had moisture there you'd have a lot more going wrong

Comment: If I remove the tail light bulbs (both sides) but the fuse still blows. Does this mean anything?

Comment: Not really if your problem is because of a short. The short is not going to be the bulb so removing it does not remove the short. I guess if you had the wrong bulbs in there it could fix it in that case.

Comment: Nothing more than you already know;  there's a short.